# Python alsaaudio and pjsip conflict

Tags: python, linux, pjsip, pyalsaaudio

I writing app in python that uses pocketsphinx and pjsip
I use pocketsphinx keyword search to wakeup the app and pjsip as phone
the problem is when I try call the "call" function and after that returning to listen to the keyword and then I get an error message from pjsip that he cannot open the sound device:

```
pjsua_aud.c  ..Opening sound device (speaker + mic) PCM@16000/1/20ms
alsa_dev.c  ...ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1557:(snd_pcm_hw_open) open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0c' failed (-16): Device or resource busy
pjsua_aud.c  ..Unable to open sound device: Unknown error from audio driver (PJMEDIA_EAUD_SYSERR) [status=420002]
operation=make_call(), error=Unknown error from audio driver (PJMEDIA_EAUD_SYSERR)
```

this error only happens when i try to return to the keyword function that uses alsaaudio

so my question will be how I can open the same audio device with pjsip and alsaaudio?